# MS-Access, having trouble making a chart that is based off a parametrized query, want to automatically pass parent fields into parameter fields?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

So, I have been working on an Access database for showing trend data, however the way the SQL server is set up, I have to make a crosstab query to get the fields I need for the trending data I want to chart. I want to chart all the data based on the start and end date times I get from the parent record of the report.

Trying to get the start and end date times automatically pushed into the query the chart has as a source is proving difficult as I have not found any good documentation to help with this.

I tried several methods, such as binding the sub report the chart will live on to the start and end date-times from the parent and trying to link them somehow. Sadly, there is no option to use these on the chart themselves.
I am using a modern chart, with the following row source query.

```
SELECT (Format([DateAndTime]," mm/dd hh:nn")) as Expr1,Avg([Vaccum]) AS VAC,AVG([Pressure]) AS PRESSURE, AVG([Temp]) AS ACTUAL TEMPERATURE 
FROM [_tempTbl]
GROUP BY (Format([DateAndTime]," mm/dd hh:nn"))
ORDER BY (Format([DateAndTime]," mm/dd hh:nn"));
```

I have a macro that creates a new table that contains the relevant data on the reports on load event.

Sample Data

| DateAndTime | Vaccum | Pressure | Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/22/2023 7:00:11.0000000 PM | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3/22/2023 7:00:21.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.1001167297363 |
| 3/22/2023 7:00:31.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.1001167297363 |
| 3/22/2023 7:00:41.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.0910720825195 |
| 3/22/2023 7:00:51.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.1001167297363 |
| 3/22/2023 7:01:01.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.1001167297363 |
| 3/22/2023 7:01:11.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.1001167297363 |
| 3/22/2023 7:01:21.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.1001167297363 |
| 3/22/2023 7:01:31.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.0729904174805 |
| 3/22/2023 7:01:41.0000000 PM | 0.3515625 | 0 | 59.0910720825195 |

Code for making a temporary table to push data to be used by the chart.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim startDate
    Dim endDate

    Const tempTableName = "_tempTbl"
    Set cdb = CurrentDb

    startDate = Me.startDate.Value
    endDate = Me.endDate.Value
restart:
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tempTableName
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdf.SQL = ("SELECT * INTO [" & tempTableName & "] FROM [trendData]")
    qdf.Parameters("startTime").Value = startDate
    qdf.Parameters("endTime").Value = endDate

    qdf.Execute
    On Error GoTo restart
    
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this ModernChart or classic MSGraph? Provide sample raw data as text table and chart RowSource query.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my post to include the missing information. For some reason, the sample data text table was not formatted correctly. @June7

Comment: One problem is use of space in field names. If spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore is exception) are used, must enclose in `[ ]`: `[ACTUAL TEMPERATURE]`. Better would be: `ActualTemperature` or `Actual_Temperature`. Also, probably should not use an alias name that is same as native field name. Why is there a space in front of "mm" in the Format() function? Why do you consider the ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses are weird?

Comment: @June7 Yes, that was throwing an error I forgot to correct it in my edit. Also sorry I made some edits so that the previous statement is not accurate to that row source query sorry.

Comment: Your table did not appear correctly because of spaces indenting each line. So the SQL statement is still not correct? I am not quite understanding issue. If temp table only has records meeting the start and end date range, where do you need to 'push' dates?

Comment: @June7, I push dates to represent the X-axis where the trends are being plotted on. Whenever I try to use this row source query on the Modern Chart it automatically applies this query to the transformed row source property 

```SELECT  FROM (SELECT (Format([DateAndTime],"mm/dd hh:nn")) as Expr1,Avg([Vaccum]) AS VAC,AVG([Pressure]) AS PRESSURE, AVG([Temp]) AS ACTUALTEMP
FROM [_tempTbl]
GROUP BY (Format([DateAndTime],"mm/dd hh:nn"))
ORDER BY (Format([DateAndTime],"mm/dd hh:nn")))```
And whenever I try to change it produces a cannot assign a value to the object error.

Comment: I can use only classic MSGraph. What type of graph do you want?

Comment: Yes, I got it sort of working with the classic MSGraph. The only issue I'm noticing with it is that it is not updating whenever the _tempTbl is deleted and recreated with new data on the report's onload() event. I also noticed that my dataset which is over 1000 records does not like the print preview.

Comment: I wouldn't use report event.

Comment: What would be better to execute the code on then? The data I want to display is dependent on what selection the user makes.

Comment: I would put it in whatever event opens the report - button Click or combobox AfterUpdate. Start and End dates are inputs by user?

Comment: @June7 No, the start and end dates are determined by an item from a list that is selected. I should look into maybe how to put that on the navigation button to go to the report itself.

Comment: Item selected from a listbox? Start and End dates could be columns in that listbox?

Comment: @June7 Nope, it's a form that displays all records in a table and start and end dates are a field the records displayed. I did manage to get it working, but I still have the issue with the print preview not displaying properly.

Comment: I don't know what 'not displaying properly' means. The aggregate query has a 1000 records? That would be a lot. What type of chart - line, bar, pie?

Comment: @June7, the chart is a line graph, I got it working. It was not displaying at all on the print preview. I fixed it by removing the formatting in the Row Source query and adding formatting to the values displayed on the X-Axis with the graph designer.